# typescript loss automatic infer type with insert object property

Tags: typescript

I'd like to insert one object to another object with array with individual.

But typescript automatic infer it return type is not what i expected.

```
const List1 = [{ lll: 'Jiyik' },{ ppp: 'Jiyik' }];

const List2 = [{ country: 'China' },{ country2: 'China2' }];


const result = List1.map(data => {
    List2.forEach(data2 => {
        return Object.assign(data,data2)
    }) 
    return data
})
```

correct output

```
{
  "lll": "Jiyik",
  "country": "China",
  "country2": "China2"
}, 
{
  "ppp": "Jiyik",
  "country": "China",
  "country2": "China2"
}]
```

But got result type

```
const result: ({
    lll: string;
    ppp?: undefined;
} | {
    ppp: string;
    lll?: undefined;
})[]
```

Comment: ① TypeScript does not model mutating existing types, and only models narrowing in some circumstances. The returned type is therefore accurate but does not include any extra properties ② You could rewrite to return new values instead of modifying existing ones, but even then TS doesn't understand using a loop to incrementally change a *type*; you'd need to refactor to use a typing that explicitly intersects its inputs, possibly like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WkqA0N) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I asked "Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?". What is your answer to that?

Comment: I was curious is there a way to use generic type to fixed mutating function like forEach?

Comment: I addressed that in ①. TypeScript does not mutate the types of existing objects that way.  I'd be happy to explain in an actual answer post, but only if I know I'm not missing something. It seems like there might be a communication barrier here?

Comment: My senerio is I’ like to defined a return type but got not assignable error

Comment: I think I need to disengage because you haven't been directly answering my questions. I think maybe there is a language barrier, which is unfortunate. Sorry I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry I won’t make it clear. Thanks anyway